# New instance declaration for Show

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to add an instance declaration in Haskell for a new data type I've created unsuccessfully. Here what I've tried so far:

```
data Prediction = Prediction Int Int Int
showPrediction :: Prediction -> String
showPrediction (Prediction a b c) = show a ++ "-" ++ show b ++ "-" ++ show c
instance Show (Prediction p) => showPrediction p
```

Seems the last line is wrong but I'm not sure how to achieve what I want. Basically is to be able to call from the interpreter a Prediction variable and get it visualized without having to call the showPrediction. Right now this works:

```
showPrediction (Prediction 1 2 3)
```

and shows:

```
"1-2-3"
```

as expected, but I would like this to work (from the interpreter):

```
Prediction 1 2 3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To derive an instance, the syntax is

```
instance «preconditions» => Class «type» where
  «method» = «definition»
```

So here, for instance, you'd have

```
instance Show Prediction where
  show (Prediction a b c) = show a ++ "-" ++ show b ++ "-" ++ show c
```

There's no precondition; you'd use that for something like `instance Show a => Show [a] where ...`, which says that *if* `a` is showable, then so is `[a]`.  Here, all `Predictions` are showable, so there's nothing to worry about.  When you wrote `instance Show (Prediction p) => showPrediction p`, you made a few mistakes.  First, `Prediction p` implies that `Prediction` is a parametrized type (one declared by, for instance, `data Prediction a = Prediction a a a`), which it isn't.  Second, `Show (Prediction p) =>` implies that *if* `Prediction P` is showable, *then* you want to declare some other instance.  And third, after the `=>`, having a function is nonsensical—Haskell wanted a type class name.

Also, for completeness's sake, there's another way to derive `Show` if you want the `Prediction 1 2 3` format for displayed output:

```
data Prediction = Prediction Int Int Int deriving Show
```

[As specified in the Haskell 98 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#derived-decls), there are only a handful of types which can be derived this way: `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show`, and `Read`.  With [the appropriate GHC extensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/deriving.html), you can also derive `Data`, `Typeable`, `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable`; you can derive any class which a `newtype`'s wrapped type derived for a `newtype`; and you can generate these automatic instances in a standalone way.

Comment: ++ high-quality, in-depth, comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply as well! The "deriving Show" worked perfectly as well. Nice to know ;))

Answer (score 19):

You've got the syntax for instances wrong. To create an instance of `Show` write:

```
instance Show Foo where
  show = ...
  -- or
  show x = ...
```

where `...` contains your definition of the `show` function for `Foo`.

So in this case you want:

```
instance Show Prediction where
  show = showPrediction
```

or, since there isn't an important reason to have `showPrediction` at all:

```
instance Show Prediction where
  show (Prediction a b c) = show a ++ "-" ++ show b ++ "-" ++ show c
```

Comment: Yup, this was it. Thanks a lot for the reply! :))

Answer (score 6):

Replace your last line with:

```
instance Show Prediction where
    show = showPrediction
```