# Haskell: Creating an instance of Show

Tags: haskell, deriving

In the code below, I define an algebraic data type and I (attempt to) make it an instance of Show.  However, I'm getting a compile-time error (included below).  What am I doing wrong?

I believe I'm using the correct syntax (atleast as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418017/haskell-new-instance-declaration-for-show)).  For context, I'm working [Problem #13 in '99 Haskell Problems'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/11_to_20)

```
data RepeatType a = Multiple (Int, a) | Single a

instance Show RepeatType where
  show (Multiple (n,x)) = "(" ++ n ++ " " ++ show x ++ ")"
  show (Single x)       = show x
```

I'm getting the following compile-time error:

```
test.hs:3:15:
    Expecting one more argument to `RepeatType'
    In the instance declaration for `Show RepeatType'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

For example, the goal is for it to work as follows in GHCi:

```
ghci> Multiple (5,'C')
(5 C)
ghci> Single 'D'
D
```

EDIT: Sorry for the totally irrelevant post title - changed now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that `RepeatType` by itself is not really a type, it's a type constructor. `Show` can only be instantiated for "proper" types, e.g. `RepeatType a`. However, for this to work you need to promise that `a` itself will be an instance of `Show`, so you will end up with something like this:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (RepeatType a) where
  show (Multiple (n,x)) = "(" ++ show n ++ " " ++ show x ++ ")"
  show (Single x)       = show x
```

(Note: you will also need to call `show` on `n` in the first part of the definition, since you cannot concatenate Ints and Strings.)